# What is the meaning of Change in Output Offset Voltage between complementary output states

Tags: voltage, current, serial, common-mode, deserialiser

I have [MAX9278](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf) deserializer IC which is connected to a 3.1inch TFT display 800 (W) * 480 (H).

Deserializer provides 4 LVDS lanes and 1 clock to the display.
While I checking the electrical voltage compatibility between the Display and the deserializer, both have a differential voltage levels of 1.125V to 1.375V. So, I believe they are compatible. But,

In the table "DC Electrical Characteristics" page 10 :

1. Does the Output Offset Voltage "Vos" actually mean Common Mode Voltage?
2. What does the "Change in VOS Between Complementary Output States - del(Vod)" & "Change in VOS Between Complementary Output States - del(Vos)" ? Can someone help me with a diagram on what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Does the Output Offset Voltage "Vos" actually mean Common Mode Voltage?

Normally, Common-Mode and Offset voltages are different things: Common-Mode voltage includes Offset, Noise, etc voltage.

> 2. What does the "Change in VOS Between Complementary Output States - del(Vod)" & "Change in VOS Between Complementary Output States - del(Vos)" ? Can someone help me with a diagram on what does this mean?

First, there's a typo in the datasheet: The first parameter should be "Change in V<sub>O***D***</sub> Between Complementary Output States - del(Vod)"

The diagram at p.22 of the datasheet shows the signaling scheme.

[image]

When the differential signal swings from high to low or vice-versa, either the offset voltage (V<sub>OS</sub>) or the differential voltage (V<sub>OD</sub>) can shift. ΔV<sub>OS</sub>  and ΔV<sub>OD</sub> indicate the maximum amount of these shifts guaranteed *(I'm not sure about that, it may not be guaranteed)* by the IC's design.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One question. Are VESA and oLDI different or the same or what are they? I couldn't find

Comment: @Newbie oLDI (a.k.a. open LVDS Interface) is the transmitting/receiving method of the signals. VESA is a mapping scheme that shows how 6- or 8-bit R, G, and B data signals are placed into the LVDS lines.